# Loading function on page load

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

Hi I have a form that is calling function when button "Calculate" is clicked. 
Following code works fine. I am trying to make it so that instead of onClick even it is submitted automatically when page is loaded. Please let me know. Thanks

```
  <form id="FormCalculate" class="readonly">      
             <input type="hidden" name="readId" id="profreadId" value=""/>
             <input type="hidden" name="taskName" id="protaskName" value=""/>
             <div class="fMain">
             <label class="fMain" for="EmailAddress">Email Address:</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-field-medium" id="emailaddress"name="Email"/>
             </div>
             <div class="xyz">
             <input type="button" class="xyz" onclick="fnCalculate()" value="Calculate" />
             </div>          
          </form>
```

Than jQuery function is

```
    function fnCalculate() {
               $("#calcStart").val(0);
               fnCrunching();
               $("#FormCalculate").submit();
           }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [$(document).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calcStart").val(0);
    fnCrunching();
    $("#FormCalculate").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger it when the page is loaded:

```
$(document).on('ready', fnCalculate);
```

Better yet, remove the `onclick` attribute entirely and use a JavaScript click handler as well:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input.xyz', fnCalculate);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/md7c7/

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery document ready function to call your function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    fnCalculate();
});
```

Note: Remove the `onclick` attribute from your button if you only want the function to be called on page load, but leave it there if you also want click events to fire the function as well.